# TYPO3 ver. 6.2.2 Bootstrap 3 - RealURL share link FB, but no image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, share, typo3, realurl

Im making a private Wine travel page, and im looking on "share link" on Facebook.
If i use this link [golf trip](http://wnf.dk/golf-vinrejser.html) and is trying to share it, it get the image fine.

But if I try the same with one of these two link, I only get the text.

[Luxenbourg](http://wnf.dk/vinrejser/tyskland/luxembourg.html)

But if i use the page ID it works fine [Luxenbourg page id](http://wnf.dk/?id=44)

[del Garda](http://wnf.dk/vinrejser/italien/del-garda.html)

Why don't it take the images and show it in facebook share, when its the long URL and not the page ID.

FIX
in TYPO3 ver. 6.2.x + Bootstrap 3.x.

Go to "Web -> Template" select root, select "Typoscript Object Browser".
Then in CONSTANTS ROOT select config.baseURL and clear it, save and add.

```
config.absRefPrefix = /
```

to the main TS, save and clear f. test and works, THX biesior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For suggesting images for pages Facebook uses linter, you can check yourself what's wrong with your page (for some reason no images are visible for Luxemburg at all - try to purge TYPO3 cache and lint again):

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwnf.dk%2Fvinrejser%2Ftyskland%2Fluxembourg.html

Best you can do is to install or create some extension which will help you with creating **og tags** it's good concept especially if you want to make your page co-working with FB on the longer run.

**Edit:** Weird, after closer look I think that's facebook's problem not TYPO3's, change a way of link creation, i.e. **remove/comment** `config.baseURL` from your TypoScript and add this in your TS (Setup) instead (don't forget to flush whole cache):

```
config.absRefPrefix = /
```

Comment: Hi biesior - I have tryed the url with the pageid, and it works 100% - so its something with the RealURL, how can I fix the issue ?

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen, check my edit to find the solution

Comment: Hi biesior thx. I have added the FIX to main question, its works 100%

Comment: Just one thing Biesior, when clear the config.baseUrl, then I still get the right links, but for the main page (forside) i get this link - http://wnf.dk/http://wnf.dk/ can I fix that somehow ?

Comment: Take a look to the code: it uses EMPTY `href` for `base` tag, you need to eliminate it absolutely! Also eliminate hrefs like `href="/http...`

Comment: right now its not showing the images, only as blank images. the links for the images is /fileadmin/..... and now it dont now to add http://www.wnf.dk before the image url, so it cant show the image.
How do i fix that ?
I know U say thats the risen, but how do i fix it, i can't se that, now i have deletet Base Url.